# Pandas to SQL failing to append

Tags: sql, pandas

I was using this code without error, but today it started to fail when i try to append or replace database.

```
#SQL Connect
conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\SQL\File.db')
c = conn.cursor()
conn.commit()

Dados.to_sql('Database', conn, index=False, if_exists='append')

sqlite3.OperationalError: table "Database" already exists
```

Comment: Do you have the full error message? Seems like your "if_exists" message should be avoiding this error but for some reason it's falling back to the default behaviour of raising errors instead?